# How to Set Delay on Android Emulator GPS Playback?

Tags: android, android-studio, kml, android-virtual-device

I want to simulate GPS movement by using Android Emulator on Android Studio's AVD. I already have a `.kml` file with the structure as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Point No. 6722</name>
      <TimeStamp>
        <when>2018-06-14T17:23:54Z</when>
      </TimeStamp>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>0.0,0.0,0.0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>

    ...

  </Document>
</kml>
```

The docs at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#timestamp said that the `<timestamp>`:

> Represents a single moment in time. This is a simple element and contains no children. Its value is a dateTime, specified in XML time (see XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition). The precision of the TimeStamp is dictated by the dateTime value in the  element.

but the `Delay` is always set to 2 secs regardless of the timestamp:

[image: Delay]

Is there any chance that I can set the delay to match the timestamp?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JohnLivermore nope. I didn't think it's possible tho and ended up setting each delay manually

Comment: Note that KML also has a "Track" tag, which is designed for GPS data, where you give it a list of times, and a corresponding list of point coordinates.  In Google Earth Pro, you can then play back a Track as an animation over time.  I have no idea if that would work in Android Emulator/Studio. For KML Track documentation, see: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtrack